ProtocolViolationException Due To Early Response
I'm having issues with writing reverse proxy logic using an HttpWebRequest for my application. From what I've observed, here's the situation:
I get a client PUT or POST request and start copying the request bytes into a Stream to the server using a looping series of Stream.WriteAsync() operations. The server immediately starts processing as soon as bytes are written to the stream. In special cases (like 429 responses), the server immediately returns a response and closes the stream while I am still writing bytes to the server request stream. My reverse proxy logic continues to copy bytes from the client request to the server request stream without any errors. Then when it calls into BeginGetResponse, I get a ProtocolViolationException that says You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.
Essentially here's the pseudocode:
void myCallback(IAsyncResult result) // ServerResponse returned while this is running
{
    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] readBuffer;
    byte[] writeBuffer;

    do
    {
        readTask = clientStream.ReadAsync(readBuffer, 0, bytesToRead);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            serverStream.WriteAsync(writeBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        bytesRead = await readTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        Swap(readBuffer, writeBuffer); // take the bytes we read and put them in the writeBuffer
    }
    while (bytesRead > 0);
}

...

ServerRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(myCallback, state);

ServerRequest.BeginGetResponse(myOtherCallback, state); // Throws ProtocolViolationException

Because of this exception, I am unable to actually receive and process the 429 response from the server properly.
I've tried flushing the request stream before calling BeginGetResponse, but it didn't seem to fix the problem. If I had to assume what was happening, it seems like the stream is being closed silently such that Stream.WriteAsync() can continue to run without getting an exception, but bytes aren't actually being written to the stream. Then when we call BeginGetResponse, the stream length isn't matching the ContentLength header, which is resulting in the exception. So flushing was essentially flushing the remaining bytes to nowhere.
I also tried using chunked encoding so I didn't have to set a ContentLength header, but the server I'm contacting failed those requests because it requires a ContentLength header.
I just want to be able to read in the response from the server regardless of when it is returned. Especially if that response says I've been throttled because I want to implement proper retry logic. Any ideas how to do that given my situation?

Use async Task in the syntax and actually await the asynchronous operations. Don't use the obsolete BeginGetRequestStream methods, these were fully replaced by async methods over 10 years ago

writing reverse proxy logic using an HttpWebRequest instead trying yourself, why not use the YARP package? YARP was created by Microsoft because a lot of internal teams kept writing their own reverse proxies over and over. As the example shows, you can create a reverse proxy with just 6 lines of code and a configuration file.
